# mouse wheel scroll horizontally

Tags: c#, focus, panel, mousewheel

I have a panel whose `AutoScroll = true;`

I can scroll the panel using scrollbars.

I also find mousewheel "vertical scroll" with "mouse" wheel by writing:

```
void panelInner_MouseWheel(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
{
    panelInner.Focus();
}
```

However, I want to scroll horizontally by "wheeling mouse + shift" too.

What do I need to do for that to happen?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Shift + mouse wheel horizontal scrolling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7828121/shift-mouse-wheel-horizontal-scrolling)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your designer file, you'll need to manually add a MouseWheel event delegate.

```
this.panelInner.MouseWheel += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.panelInner_MouseWheel);
```

Then, in your code behind, you can add the following.

```
    private const int WM_SCROLL = 276; // Horizontal scroll 
    private const int SB_LINELEFT = 0; // Scrolls one cell left 
    private const int SB_LINERIGHT = 1; // Scrolls one line right

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int wMsg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam); 

    private void panelInner_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ModifierKeys == Keys.Shift)
        {
            var direction = e.Delta > 0 ? SB_LINELEFT : SB_LINERIGHT;

            SendMessage(this.panelInner.Handle, WM_SCROLL, (IntPtr)direction, IntPtr.Zero);
        }
    }
```

References:

1. [Shift + mouse wheel horizontal scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7828121/shift-mouse-wheel-horizontal-scrolling)
2. [Mouse tilt wheel horizontal scrolling in C#](http://www.philosophicalgeek.com/2007/07/27/mouse-tilt-wheel-horizontal-scrolling-in-c/)

Comment: I saw this answer in the forum but I cant understand it :S can you explain more?

Comment: this entry"[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)] " will placed where ? also richTextBox? why do we use it ?

Comment: I asked because when I wrote this : [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]  this entry does not compiled

Comment: You might need to add this namespace on the top, using System.Runtime.InteropServices; OR [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]

Comment: also richTextBox? why do we use it ? – user1458850 8 mins ago

Comment: Last question is how to increase the velocity of scrolling ?

Comment: I am sorry, I am new, I miss it, know I think I did what you want?

Comment: Thanks, try to play around with http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.mouseeventargs.delta.aspx. It might help you. Also look at this post, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825380/mousewheel-event-fire

Comment: I found that, but these are not enough if I choose Page up Page down then scroll moves so fast, ı need more smooth velocity 

    private const int WM_SCROLL = 276; // Horizontal scroll
    private const int WM_VSCROLL = 277; // Vertical scroll
    private const int SB_LINEUP = 0; // Scrolls one line up